# Remove metadata from Elasticsearch response

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have written the below query:

```
GET _search{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "datetime" : {
                "from" : "2016-12-05T00:00:00", 
                "to" : "2016-12-15T00:00:00"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to remove metadata information from the response or only have `_source` field in response.

Is it something that I can add in above query to remove it?

Java code would also be fine to me.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Response Filtering to by specifying the filter_path in your query to control the response returned by elastic search.

```
GET /_search?q=elasticsearch&filter_path=hits.hits.fields
```

Reference - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#_response_filtering